# Quality of inline image on iPhone emails

Tags: html, css, iphone, html-email

We are using a Python script to generate emails every day and send out daily reports to business users.
Inside of these emails we adding PrintScreen of the report. In that case, the users can see the results (numbers of the report) inside of the email with no need to open attachments (PDF) on mobile phones.

But the problem is that for some iPhone models the image is very blurry and it is impossible to see the content of the image.
There is no problem with Android phones.

Is there any way to say for iPhone like **Please do not shrink the quality of the image so much.**

The function to add an image:

```
def send_email(send_to, subject, html, plain, img_path, cc):
try:
    # prepare date for email subject
    scorecard_date = date.today() - timedelta(1)

    # prepare message
    msg = MIMEMultipart() 
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = send_to
    msg['Subject'] = subject + ' - for ' + scorecard_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

    # attach cc if applicable
    if cc is not None:
        msg['Cc'] = cc
        send_to = [send_to, cc]

    # attach plain or html body
    if html is not None:
        msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))
    else:
        msg.attach(MIMEText(plain, 'plain'))

    # attach image if applicable
    if img_path is not None:    
        fp = open(img_path, 'rb')
        msg_image = MIMEImage(fp.read())
        msg_image.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
        msg.attach(msg_image)
        fp.close()

    # create server instance and send email
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, smtp_port)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user, sc.get_email_pass())
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(email_user, send_to, text)
    server.quit()

    # return ok
    return 0
except:
    # something went wrong - probably timeout
    return 1
```

HTML tags where image is inserte inside of the body of email:

```
<div style="line-height:15px;font-size:1px">&#160;</div>  <img class="left  autowidth  fullwidth" align="left" border="0" src="cid:image1" alt="Image" title="Image" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: block !important;border: 0;height: auto;float: none;width: 150%;max-width: 1024px" width="1024">
```

Thank you,
Darius

Answer (score 0):

iPhone is using what we call retina display. In short these devices *have a higher pixel density than other traditional Apple displays*.

What Apple have done is placed 2 pixels in place of 1. Which means your images are half the size of whats its supposed to show at.

Example if your image is set to 200px x 200px, Apple will show it as 200px x 200px but in a space of 400px x 400px space (on their device) which means you images are resized to fit that space.

You will need to take a screenshot and show it at a smaller size on iOS to get around the retina display.

Models that have retina display can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_display#Models).